# Fixing for windowing function in FFT

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I've been learning about the FFT and about the usefulness of windowing functions. A problem I'm running into is the affect of windowing functions on the amplitude of signals in the FFT. For example, lets say I have a signal that is equal to:

```
y = 5.0 * sin(50.0 * 2.0 * pi * x) + 1.0 * sin(80.0 * 2.0 * pi * x)
```

And then I want to perform an FFT and receive the following plot:

[image]

Then if I perform a kaiser windowing function of the 14th degree, I receive the following FFT:

[image]

What I'm wanting to do is the following: Given a signal, I want to extract a wave out of it of a frequency I approximately know. To do this, I'd like to apply a windowing function to make it clearer what the frequency is I'm trying to extract but not lose information about the amplitude of wave I'm trying to extract. Is this possible? Like a way to reverse the amplitude decrease from the windowing function.

Comment: Please provide the code you used to perform the windowing. Perhaps you forgot to normalize the window to the correct amplitude.

Comment: This is more DSP theory than programming- probably better to ask on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

All Windowing functions will change the perceived amplitudes. Remember, windowing functions are changing the signal, albeit in a way that serves a particular purpose.

So, to get meaningful amplitudes, you'll have to do some "normalization". Most windowing functions have documented normalizations.

But, I don't really thing you need them, in most cases. Windowing functions are mostly used to help you detect the "peaks". Once you've found the peaks, you can just use the FFT(DFT) results of the same "bins" (before the windowing function).